# API request takes some seconds on react app but not in postman

Tags: reactjs, request, postman

fellow programmers,
There is an API that I created from NodeJS(express).

Problem comes when I call it from my React-App.

When I call same API from Postman it takes miliseconds but when I call it from my React-App
it takes around 7-9seconds to resolve its response.

My React-App API resolving time!
[My React APP Response time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlwow.png)

Postman response time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvUAA.png)

My React Code:
[API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBs33.png)
[Controller Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSO0S.png)

Can anyone help! Its bugging me from week. Please and thank you!